# Prove that $Z_f = {(x,f(x)) : x \in \mathbb{R}}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: real-analysis

Given two subsets $X, Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$:
$$d(X,Y) = inf{\|x−y\| : x \in X,y \in Y}$$
Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Prove that $Z_f = {(x,f(x)) : x \in \mathbb{R}}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Should I just show $Z$ is bounded so it's closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bounded sets are not closed and the question has nothing to do with boundedness. Instead show that the limit of any convergent sequence  in the given set belongs to the set.

If $(x_n,f(x_n))$ is a sequence in the given set which $ \to (a,b)$ in $\mathbb  R^{2}$ then $x_n \to a$ and $f(x_n) \to b$. By continuity we get $f(x_n) \to f(a)$. Since limits are unique we get $b=f(a)$ so $(a,b)$ belongs to the given set. Hence the set is closed.

Comment: and the variables a and b are just dummy variables, so it becomes ANY convergent sequence?

Comment: @GarlicSTAT Yes. I started with any convergent sequence in $Z_f$ denoted the limit by $(a,b)$.